# Simplifying Code for Hashset Duplicate Detector

Tags: java, duplicates, hashset

Here is the code I have that checks reads a film into a hashset and detects whether or not the film contains duplicate.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    boolean hasDuplicate = false;
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();        
    BufferedReader list = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(args[0]));     
    while(list.ready() && (hasDuplicate == false)){                         
        set.add(list.readLine());   
        if(set.contains(list.readLine())) hasDuplicate = true;                          
    }
    if(hasDuplicate == true){ 
        System.out.println("NOT UNIQUE");
    }else{ 
        System.out.println("UNIQUE");
    }
    list.close();           
}
```

Is there a way for me to simplify

```
while(list.ready() && (hasDuplicate == false)){                         
        set.add(list.readLine());   
        if(set.contains(list.readLine())) hasDuplicate = true;                          
    }
```

so that I only need to call for the hashset once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `add` method returns `true` if the item wasn't already in the Set. So you can simply call and just chech the result:

```
while(list.ready() && (hasDuplicate == false)){                         
    if (!set.add(list.readLine()))
         hasDuplicate = true;                          
  }
```

Secondly the original code wouldn't work anyway because the line was read twice and used only once for adding and once for checking. In other words it ignored half of the input.

Answer (score 1):

[`HashSet#add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add-E-) returns `true` if the set did not contain the specified element. So you could just do something like:

```
while(list.ready() && (hasDuplicate == false)){                         
    hasDuplicate = !set.add(list.readLine());   
}
```

This is slightly confusing though, so I would re-word your variables so it looks more like this:

```
while(list.ready() && noDuplicates){                         
    noDuplicates = set.add(list.readLine());   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you can consider.

1. Java Set will returns false if it is a duplicate entry

> `boolean isDuplicate= !set.add(list.readLine());`

2. If you call `readline` second time it will read next line.

> ```
> set.add(list.readLine());   
> if(set.contains(list.readLine())) hasDuplicate = true;
> ```

3. Boolean need not to be compared with equal operator

> (hasDuplicate == false)

Comment: The codes doesn't work properly if I use `hasDuplicate = false` or `!hasDuplicate`.